# What will be the problems if 2 users receive the same OTP in an arbitrary time gap?

Tags: one-time-password

First of all, I sincerely apologise if this question has already been asked before. I searched in Google and on this website but was unable to find any article.

I have seen that most OTPs are 6 digits in length. That means at most 999,999 OTPs can be generated by a system. But what if at a certain point of time more than 999,999 OTPs are required?

I know that one OTP should be generated only once. Then how should the system be able to cope up with the above-mentioned problem?

Suppose that user A receives an OTP 123456 at a certain point of time. User A either uses the OTP or the OTP gets expired. Then after, say 6 months (arbitrary time period), user X also receives the same OTP 123456. What problem(s) may arise in this condition?

Comment: Why are you subtracting 99,999?

Comment: I meant to say that the system can generate at most 900,000 OTPs (including 100000). I tried to show how I am getting this 900,000 figure. Should I remove it?

Comment: What about 000000 - 099999? You're probably thinking of it as a number rather than a collection of 6 digits, 0s on the left are allowed.

Comment: You are right. I have edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no issues. Each OTP is linked to a specific user for a specific time. If it's an OTP sent via email or SMS it's likely in its own database table with a user id and expiration. If it's HOTP or TOTP the key(s) would be linked to the user and expiration is built into the algorithm.

> I know that one OTP should be generated only once.

No. Each OTP should only be **used** once, and invalidated after use. There is no requirement that every OTP must be unique and never used again.

If an OTP is generated and then used, it may be generated and used again in the future, but at any point in time the only valid OTPs are those that were generated but not yet used or expired.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarifications. Especially the "I know that one OTP should be generated only once" part.